# How to reflect a vector on a line $x=\lambda d$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

How would one evaluate the below question? I tried considering the case in $R^2$, where a vector $p$ is reflected on $x=\lambda d$ to produce a vector $q$, but I struggled to do that itself, let alone $R^n$. Thanks.

**Let $p$ be the position vector of a point $P$ in $R^n$ and let $q$ be the position vector of the point $Q$ which is the reflection of P in the line 
$$x=\lambda d, \lambda \in R$$
Show that the function $T:R^n->R^n$ defined by $T(p)=q$ is a linear map. Hence, find a matrix $A$ which transforms $p$ into $q$, i.e. $T(p)=Ap=q$.**

Comment: Have a look at [Householder reflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation). The hyperplane through the origin in your example is the line $x = \lambda d$.

Comment: You should not post images of the question. If the link expires your question will not be understandable. Please use Mathjax to enter the equations with similar syntax as LaTeX.

Comment: What is $d$ ? A scalar ? If yes, you are dealing with vertical lines (for example $x=3$), is it so ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I wondered about that too, I believe it's a vector.